# List/remove files, with filenames containing string that's "more than a month ago"?

Tags: bash, python

I store some data in files which follow this naming convention:

```
/interesting/data/filename-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM
```

How do I look for the ones with `date in file name < now - 1 month` and delete them?

Files may have changed since they were created, so searching according to `last modification date` is not good.

What I'm doing now, is [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter)-ing them in python:

```
prefix = '/interesting/data/filename-'

import commands
names = commands.getoutput('ls {0}*'.format(prefix)).splitlines()

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

all_files = map(lambda name: {
    'name': name,
    'date': datetime.strptime(name, '{0}%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M'.format(prefix))
}, names)

month = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 30)
to_delete = filter(lambda item: item['date'] < month, all_files)

import os
from operator import itemgetter
map(os.remove, map(itemgetter('name'), to_delete))
```

Is there a (oneliner) `bash` solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `-ctime` with `find`?  For a file, `ctime` indicates the last time the file metadata has changed (file creation, rename, chmod, chown, chgrp, etc).  For most logfiles, creation date and ctime would be the same.

Comment: According to `man find`: *`-ctime n` File’s status was last changed n\*24 hours ago.* That only returns filenames from that exact date, but in my case there may be files older than than, and I can't tell how old they are, so I really need a ` < ` or ` <= ` comparison.

Comment: You are right. `man find` says: *Numeric arguments can be specified as: `+n` (for greater than n), `-n` (for less than n), `n` (for exactly n).* And it works as desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming GNU date and GNU find you can do it this way

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prefix="/interesting/data/filename-"
ref=/tmp/ref.$$
one_month_ago=/tmp/one_month_ago.$$
results=/tmp/results.$$

# create a file whose timestamp is "one month ago"
touch "$one_month_ago" -t $(date -d "-1 month" +%Y%m%d%I%M.%S)

while read -r file ; do
        # strip the prefix, leaving the suffix
        datestr=$(tail -c $(( ${#file} - ${#prefix} + 1 )) <<<"$file")

        # cut the date and time out of the suffix
        date=$(cut -d- -f1-3 <<<"$datestr")
        time=$(cut -d- -f 4- <<<"$datestr" | tr - :)

        # create a reference file whose timestamp matches the string from $file
        touch "$ref" -t $(date -d "$date $time" +%Y%m%d%I%M.%S)

        # ask find whether the reference file is not neewer (aka "is older") 
        # than one month ago
        find "$ref" -not -newer "$one_month_ago" > "$results" &&
                # results from find?
                [ -s "$results" ] &&
                # then rm the corresponding file
                echo rm -f -- "$file"

done < <(find -path "$prefix"'*')

# clean up
rm -f "$ref" "$one_month_ago" "$results"
```

But it's not exactly a oneliner.

Since this is under tested and somewhat dangerous I have included an `echo` prefix to the `rm` command, so you'll need to remove that once you verify that the results are correct.

One weakness here is in the initial selection of files. `-path "$prefix"'*'` presumes absolute paths and will break otherwise; a more intelligent selection is probably better, even if it's a simple shell glob (i.e., replace the while loop with `for file in "$prefix*" ; do ... done`. I didn't do this because I don't know whether or not such a glob expansion would overflow the maximum command length.

Comment: Interesting, it actually does the compares.  It will be a bit slower because of all the `touch` files.  The `find . ! -newer' can much more simply be replaced by the `[ $FILE1 -ot $FILE2 ]` flag, at least in bash.

Comment: Given all of the GNUisms present, including the explicit invocation of bash and the use of non-portable find syntax, I don't think anyone could object to the use of `-ot`. I would have used this comparison if I had thought about it, but instead I recycled a solution I've used before (when I had GNU find on Windows, but no sh).

Comment: As it turns out you can use `-newerXY` where `Y` is `t` to specify a timestamp directly (for GNU `find` it's GNU `date -d` format) to avoid the need to create an intermediate file. This will be a little faster, as Rich mentions.